# How to reference part of your own text?

Tags: citing, page

I am writing a book and I want to quote part of my text.

Example:

How to cite: "Authors. Title: Publisher, Location, 2023. p. 10 - 20"

I am writing the page numbers manually. I would like a command for this.

My code:

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\chapter{Test)

Authors. Title: Publisher, Location, 2023. p. 10 - 20

bla bla bla

\printbibliography

\end{refsection}
```

Comment: Please give an English title to your question.

Comment: I fixed the title, translating into English.

Comment: Welcome. // Do you ask, what the convention is in literature, or do you want to implement some Latex commands, regardless of any convention?

Comment: You could insert `\label{key}` and then use `\pageref{key}` somewhere else to get a page number of a link. Alternatively, `hyperref` package provides a more convenient approach via `\hypertarget{link:key}{display text}` and `\hyperlink{link:key}{display text}`, which lets you display texts of both a link and a target.